# React immutable List return undefined item after push method

Tags: immutability

I'm new in React. I tried to build an sample application look like Todos app and using immutable Store

// My Store

```
import {List }  from 'immutable';  
constructor() {
    this.id = '';
    this.name = '';
    this.todos = List();
}

addTodo(todo){
    this.setState({
        todos: this.todos.push(toto)
    });
}
```

// My component

```
import Immutable   from 'immutable';
import UUID        from 'node-uuid';

var newTodo = Immutable.fromJS({ id: UUID.v4(), name: '', content:'' });
```

...
When I pushed new todo
addTodo(newTodo)

and: console.log(this.todos)

--> It always returned

Object[undefined]

Anyone can explain me the reason why it always returns undefined object in List?
Thank in advance